# Starting tomcat Error code 4 : Failed

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm creating multiple instances of tomcat using opscode chef cookbook. I see that tomcat.conf was not written into my instance of tomcat but is only in the base instance. I created a softlink to the base instance tomcat.conf file. When I tried to start the server, I get the following error with no logs. There are no logs in /var/log or tomcat folder. Please provide hints on how to debug.

```
[root@centosclient2 ~]# service tomcat6-obi_sandbox_tomcat start
Starting tomcat6-obi_sandbox_tomcat: Error code 4          [FAILED]
```

I saw below in /var/log/tomcat6-obi_sandbox_tomcat-initd.log

```
-sh: /usr/sbin/tomcat6-obi_sandbox_tomcat: No such file or directory
```

Apparently there is no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into error code 4 a few times, and the problem was that disk was full.